# Help with renaming a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora

First off, I need to do be in the ASSIGNMENT1 folder (which I am) and I need help renaming M1 to Misc#1 file under the Level2-Misc directory. I tried doing `mv M1 Misc#1`, but it gives me `mv: cannot stat 'M1': No such file or directory`. I tried to run this command from the ASSIGNMENT1 folder. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: When asking questions, you need to tell us what commands you ran, what you expect them to do, and what they actually did instead. You say you got an error. OK, what error? You say you ran the `mv` command, but where from? Please [edit] your question, [replace the image with text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/) (you can copy/paste it into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code), explain what you did in more detail (the exact command and where you ran it from) and show us the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You're in the 'ASSIGNMENT1' directory, and `mv` is telling you that there is no directory by the name of 'M1'. And that makes sense from the directory tree - the 'M1' directory is under the sub-directories 'Level-D3' and 'Level2-Misc', not in the 'ASSIGNMENT1' directory where you're running the command.

So for `mv` to work, you have two options. The first is to give it the full path to the directories (source and target). From the 'ASSIGNMENT1' directory, you could run the following command:

```
mv Level-D3/Level2-Misc/M1 Level-D3/Level2-Misc/Misc#1
```

The second option is to descend into the sub-directory containing 'M1', and then do the rename. Again, from the 'ASSIGNMENT1' directory, run:

```
cd Level-D3/Level2-Misc
mv M1 Misc#1
```

Either approach will give you the result you want. The choice is just one of preference. The first approach lets you remain in the 'ASSIGNMENT1' directory. The second approach saves you some typing.